# stop customize.php redirect to login page if admin is not logged in

Tags: wp-admin, redirect, login

How can i disable /wp-admin/customize.php redirect to login page when accessed directly?

I want to use customize.php if user logged in as admin, but when user is not logged in i want to disable the redirect to the login page.

Comment: how is it different from your previous question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to disable every admin redirects without plugin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/286924/is-there-any-way-to-disable-every-admin-redirects-without-plugin)

Comment: not duplicate anymore :)

Comment: cool, but yuo could just edit the first one.

Comment: If you don't want to redirect when no user is connected, what do you want to show ?

Comment: @mmm redirect to the siteurl.

Answer (score 0):

to redirect all admin pages to home page when the user is not connected, try that

```
add_filter("login_url", function ($login_url, $redirect, $force_reauth) {

    if (!is_user_logged_in()) {
        $login_url = home_url("/");
    }


    return $login_url;

}, 10, 3);
```

If you want to redirect only on the page "customize.php", you can add the condition at the "if".

Comment: not working for me.